# Como fazer aparecer os eixos de um histograma com suas respectivas classes no R?

Tags: r, histograma

Eu ploto um histograma da variável peso na minha planilha de dados mas ele aparece sem os eixos. O código que usei foi:

```
hist(rehab.1$PESO, main = "", axes = F, xlab = "Peso(kg)", ylab = "frequências absolutas",col = 'green')
```

[image: Esse é o histograma que obtenho]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está passando `FALSE` para o parâmetro `axes` da função `hist` (que controla se os eixos aparecem ou não). Remova o `axes = F`, ou troque para `axes = TRUE`, e os eixos serão desenhados.

Comment: Valeu @carlosfigueira deu certo agora \o/. Comecei a estudar o R essa semana e ainda estou bem perdido, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @ClovesAdriano Se a resposta do Carlos resolveu seu problema, clique no ícone de check do lado do texto que ela fique marcada como a melhor resposta, e a pergunta como resolvida! Assim conseguimos organizar melhor o site e o Carlos recebe a reputação que merece.